# Should i keep one docker registry per one microservice image for all the environment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, docker-registry

I am working on microservice architecture based application. I have

- N number of microservices
- All are on docker

Docker Compose is taking care of running and building. Now project is at stage where it should be deployed to below listed environments,

- Development
- QA/Staging
- Pre-Production
- Production

My question is how should I manage images of all microservices

- Should it be one image registry for one microservice and all environment?
- Should it be one image registry for all microservice for all environment?
- Should it be one image registry for one microservice per environment?
- Should it be one image registry for all microservice per environment?
  Cloud provide I have in mind are AWS and GCP.

I am really not able to find any recommendation on this topic and could not decide how I should proceed.
I am requesting your guidance on this.

Thank you
Dheeraj Kumar

Comment: First of all, you should use the same IMAGE for all environments, so the question is not well-formed I guess.

Comment: Well what i have in mind that images built for dev and test will have different base image like - FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk

and for production - FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet
hope this helps

even if i use same image how should i keep it in registry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one registry for all environments. There will be too much to pull the image, retag the image and push the image to new registry - there is too many things that can go wrong, and too little value.

What you may want to do is to have a separate registry for *Development* and another registry for "automated environments". With "automated environments", I mean in a CI/CD-pipeline, after the developer has pushed code to Git, there should be automated build jobs. The reason for this separation is that you may want to have different authentication requirements and separate what you *trust* (e.g. is scanned) and not.

You don't need separate *registry* for each microservice, but you may want to have a separate [Repository](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/) for each microservice.